# Django : NoReverseMatch for HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django

I am trying to Redirect to the post's page soon as it's saved , well it's saved but the redirection won't work , it's working very fine on the development server .. not in the production one .

I tried :

```
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('emr.main.views.viewprofile', args=(profile.id,)))
```

Well it's working fine but, in production host i have to change emr.main.view.viewprofile to myproject.main.views.viewprofile ! because viewprofile itself it's not working

then i got template syntax error :

> TemplateSyntaxError Exception Value:    Caught NoReverseMatch while
>   rendering: Reverse for 'main.views.add_record' with arguments
>   '(47L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

main.view.add_comment which is a url tag 
Add record

how to solve this issue ?

url.py

```
    (r'^add/record/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/?$', add_record),
(r'^add/current/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/?$', add_current),
```

Edit :

The main issues are :

1. Naming the APP/views needs to rename all the files to fix this for development instead of emr.main.views.add_records to myproject.main.views.. since function itself is not working
2. URL tags such as {% url main.views.add_record profile.id %} still returning errors ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a tuple to [`reverse()`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L344) whereas the function expects a list.

Try `args=[profile.id]` instead.

However, it's difficult to answer this properly without seeing the function definition (or at least signature) for the `viewprofile()` function.

Comment: well this solve the issue though , stuck in naming the function :(

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use named url's, as this sounds like a Python path issue with your views.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url

It would also be helpful if you would post your urls.py config.

Comment: well i posted the url.py for the relevant urls

Comment: can you give me an example how naming the url will solve this problem , well i believe it's a python path issue cause it's working fine on the development server ...

Comment: Well you said that on your production server, "emr.main.view.viewprofile" didn't work, but when you changed it to "myproject.main.views.viewprofile", it did. So it seems that on the server, your root path is "myproject".

Sadly you didn't give the entire urls.py, so I can't see which function prepend you used. Please post your entire urls.py patterns, and also the ROOT_URLCONF setting in settings.py

Comment: Fixed turns out i missed with the url.py to work only with emr as absolute .. Thank YOU for your help best regards